# redirect to a controller function through account authentication link

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am implementing account verification through email in codeigniter, my code to send email is

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('example@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('example@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('
    Thanks for signing up!
    Your account has been created, click this link to activate your account
    <a href='.base_url('verify').$user_id.'/'.'1221212'.'>Your Activation Link</a>');
$this->email->send();
```

it is working great (user receives email), now what I want is, to redirect the user to my controller function when he clicks the link.

Function to which I want to redirect is (written using internet help)

```
function view_verify($id,$rand)
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
```

and I have added this in my routes.php in config.php (written using internet help)

```
$route['verify/(:any)']    = "user/view_verify/$1";
```

it is not working when I click the link, page not found error occurs
How to sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the function 'view_verify' is written in the controller named as 'user', if yes 
then try browsing the view_verify url through browser first, instead of using it directly in the mail.

your url will be

```
http://DOMAIN-NAME/CONTROLLER-NAME/view_verify/user_id/1221212
```

First check whether the above url is working or not, if its working fine then use the routes as mentioned by Kumar_v, like

```
$route['verify/(:any)/(:any)']    = "user/view_verify/$1/$2";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing two parameters

Try this code.

```
$route['verify/(:any)/(:any)']    = "user/view_verify/$1/$2";
```